# how to show listbox string to another listbox

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class frmAppliances
    Private Sub frmAppliances_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lstApp.Items.Add(New Product("Electric fan", 500.0))
        lstApp.Items.Add(New Product("Refrigerator", 9000.0))
        lstApp.Items.Add(New Product("Washing Machine", 4000.0))
        lstApp.Items.Add(New Product("Oven Toaster", 550.0))
        lstApp.Items.Add(New Product("Flat Iron", 350.0))
        lstApp.Items.Add(New Product("VCD Player", 1200.0))
        lstApp.Items.Add(New Product("Mini Component", 3500.0))
        lstApp.Items.Add(New Product("Television", 5000.0))
        lstApp.Items.Add(New Product("Air Conditioner", 10000.0))
        lstApp.Items.Add(New Product("Rice Cooker", 600.0))
        lstApp.Items.Add(New Product("Electric Stove", 1000.0))
        lstApp.Items.Add(New Product("Electric Pot", 800.0))
        lstApp.Items.Add(New Product("Karaoke", 2500.0))
        lstApp.Items.Add(New Product("Microwave Oven", 3000.0))
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstApp_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstApp.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim prc As Double = CType(lstApp.SelectedItem, Product).Price
        lstPrice.Items.Add(prc)
        Dim parts As String = lstApp.Items.ToString()
        lstSold.Items.Add(parts)

    End Sub

    Public Class Product
        Public Name As String
        Public Price As Double

        Public Sub New(ByVal pName As String, ByVal pPrice As Double)
            Name = pName
            Price = pPrice
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return Name
        End Function
    End Class
```

It says windows system form objection in the listbox that I want to show, the other listbox is for the price.

Comment: *"It says windows system form objection in the listbox"*. No it doesn't. In this case, we can work out what it actually says but that may not always be the case so please provide the actual information rather than a vague approximation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```vb
Dim parts As String = lstApp.Items.ToString()
```

The `Items` property is a collectiion of all the items in the `ListBox` so why would you think that displaying a `String` representation of that would be of use here? Like the vast majority of types, its `ToString` method simply returns the name of the type. You already know how to get a value from the selected item because you're doing iit for the `Price`, so why would you think that doing it for the `Name` would be any different?

```vb
Dim selectedProduct = DirectCast(lstApp.SelectedItem, Product)
Dim price = selectedProduct.Price
Dim name = selectedProduct.Name
lstPrice.Items.Add(price)
lstSold.Items.Add(name)
```

That said, you're going about this in the wrong way altogether. Firstly, you should pretty much ALWAYS use properties rather than field:

```vb
Public Class Product
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Price As Double

    Public Sub New(name As String, price As Double)
        Me.Name = name
        me.Price = price
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function
End Class
```

Next, you should be creating a list of `Product` objects and binding that to the control:

```vb
Dim products = {New Product("Electric fan", 500.0),
                New Product("Refrigerator", 9000.0),
                New Product("Washing Machine", 4000.0),
                New Product("Oven Toaster", 550.0),
                New Product("Flat Iron", 350.0),
                New Product("VCD Player", 1200.0),
                New Product("Mini Component", 3500.0),
                New Product("Television", 5000.0),
                New Product("Air Conditioner", 10000.0),
                New Product("Rice Cooker", 600.0))
                New Product("Electric Stove", 1000.0),
                New Product("Electric Pot", 800.0),
                New Product("Karaoke", 2500.0),
                New Product("Microwave Oven", 3000.0)}

With lstApp
    .DisplayMember = "Name"
    .ValueMember = "Price"
    .DataSource = products
End With
```

Note that data-binding requires properties. Finally, you can get the `Name` and `Price` of the selected `Product` like so:

```vb
lstSold.Items.Add(lstApp.Text)
lstPrice.Items.Add(CDbl(lstApp.SelectedValue))
```

You should pretty much always use data-binding if it is an option.